# Material-ui Tabs not rendering properly in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am using Material-UI in a nextjs app and some components just don't render. One of them is the Tabs components. I don't know if I am missing some important config somewhere.

This is my code and results:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  navRow: {
    width: `100vw`,
    display: 'flex',
    height: '15%',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
}))


const Page = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event, activeTab) => {
        setActiveTab(activeTab);
    };

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.navRow}>
          <Tabs
            value={activeTab}
            onChange={handleChange}
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            centered
          >
            <Tab label="Item One" />
            <Tab label="Item Two" />
            <Tab label="Item Three" />
          </Tabs>
        </Paper>
    )

}
```

And this is the weird output that I get:

[image: material-ui not rendering tabs]

**EDIT:**

For more context that might help, when I use Tabs, I get the following warnings/errors on the server-side console:

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `fullWidth` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `fullwidth` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in svg
    in ForwardRef(SvgIcon)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(SvgIcon))
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon)
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon) (at search.js:127)
    in div
    in div
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Tabs)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Tabs)) (at search.js:120)
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Paper)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (at search.js:108)
    in div (at Layout.js:9)
    in Layout (at search.js:107)
    in Search (at _app.js:29)
    in Context.Provider (at _app.js:28)
    in Context.Provider
    in ThemeProvider (at _app.js:26)
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Consumer
    in ApolloProvider (at _app.js:25)
    in App (at _document.js:58)
    in Context.Provider
    in StylesProvider
    in Unknown
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in AppContainer
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `indicator`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: indicator="false" or indicator={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with indicator={condition && value}, pass indicator={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
    in svg
    in ForwardRef(SvgIcon)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(SvgIcon))
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon)
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon) (at search.js:127)
    in div
    in div
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Tabs)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Tabs)) (at search.js:120)
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Paper)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (at search.js:108)
    in div (at Layout.js:9)
    in Layout (at search.js:107)
    in Search (at _app.js:29)
    in Context.Provider (at _app.js:28)
    in Context.Provider
    in ThemeProvider (at _app.js:26)
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Consumer
    in ApolloProvider (at _app.js:25)
    in App (at _document.js:58)
    in Context.Provider
    in StylesProvider
    in Unknown
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in AppContainer
Warning: React does not recognize the `selectionFollowsFocus` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `selectionfollowsfocus` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in svg
    in ForwardRef(SvgIcon)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(SvgIcon))
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon)
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon) (at search.js:127)
    in div
    in div
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Tabs)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Tabs)) (at search.js:120)
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Paper)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (at search.js:108)
    in div (at Layout.js:9)
    in Layout (at search.js:107)
    in Search (at _app.js:29)
    in Context.Provider (at _app.js:28)
    in Context.Provider
    in ThemeProvider (at _app.js:26)
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Consumer
    in ApolloProvider (at _app.js:25)
    in App (at _document.js:58)
    in Context.Provider
    in StylesProvider
    in Unknown
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in AppContainer
Warning: React does not recognize the `textColor` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `textcolor` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in svg
    in ForwardRef(SvgIcon)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(SvgIcon))
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon)
    in ForwardRef(TabIcon) (at search.js:127)
    in div
    in div
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Tabs)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Tabs)) (at search.js:120)
    in div
    in ForwardRef(Paper)
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (at search.js:108)
    in div (at Layout.js:9)
    in Layout (at search.js:107)
    in Search (at _app.js:29)
    in Context.Provider (at _app.js:28)
    in Context.Provider
    in ThemeProvider (at _app.js:26)
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Consumer
    in ApolloProvider (at _app.js:25)
    in App (at _document.js:58)
    in Context.Provider
    in StylesProvider
    in Unknown
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in AppContainer
```

Comment: I'm not seeing ```handleChange```?

Comment: Hello @Medi I have updated to include the onChange. But that doesn't have an effect on the issue.

Comment: If you remove `className={classes.navRow}` to Paper do you see Tabs correctly?

Comment: Which material ui tabs are you using?

Comment: @Medi [this](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/) one.

Comment: What you see here is exactly what is in the documentation @GiovanniEsposito. The only difference being that I renamed the class name from `root` to `navRow`

Comment: There are Simple Tabs, Fixed tabs, Scrollable Tabs, Customized Tabs, ...etc. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I am using `Simple Tabs` but I think this issue is not specific to tabs. For now, I just want to use Tabs. Not that I have installed `@material-ui/icons` and `@material-ui/core`

Comment: I just made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-drr9o?file=/demo.js) and I was not able to reproduce your error. I missed something?

Comment: As it seems, you accidentally forgot to copy <TabPanel /> component. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-146u4?file=/demo.js).

Comment: Yes you are right but I just copy the OP code just to be 100% aligned with him (but of course without TabPanel  Tabs are totally useless...)

Comment: I am using this in NextJS. could that have something to do with this?

Comment: Seems that you can use Material UI with Next.js but you have to do 2 steps before use it... Take a look at [this](https://itnext.io/next-js-with-material-ui-7a7f6485f671)

Comment: Thank you for the artical, @GiovanniEsposito. I have made all the changes recommended in the article but the issue persists. I have updated my question with some more logs. Perhaps those might shed some light on the root cause of the issue.